# Re-orderable custom collectionview layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I sub-classed `UIcollectionViewLayout` to create my own layout. In the `prepareLayout()` method I create the frames for the attributes of each cell because I know where they should be. The frames for each cell are hardcoded. However, I can't hard-code the position of the frames because I want to be able to drag and drop cells. `UICollectionViews` have nice functions for that:

```
`collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(_:position)`.
```

But this function can't change the location of the cells if their position is hard-coded.

Additionally if the cell is not in it's position it seems to disappear from the view. I want to dynamically change the position of a cell when I begin to drag it. Should I call `invalidateLayout()` somewhere? I have a `UICollectionView` as a `subview` of my `UIViewcontroller`.

So I've attached a `longPress` gesture recognizer to my collection view.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue few months ago, you cant reload selected cells, the only way is reload whole Collection View. If you have any other solution, pls share me. Thanks